# Using Generic Types with Injected Services in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .NET Core Application which is migrating to Blazor from Angular.
I have a service that takes a generic type so that it can be extended in various other solutions.

```
public class Service<TUser> : IService<TUser> where TUser : BaseUser, new() {
    private readonly RoleManager<AuthRole> _roleManager
}
```

This is registered for dependency injection as follows

```
services.AddTransient<IService<TUser>, Service<TUser>();
```

This is how the controllers use the service

```
public class ServiceController<TUser> where TUser : AuthUser, new()
{
    private readonly IService<TUser> _service;
```

I am then injecting this into my blazor component, which is unhappy because TUser is undefined.

I have tried using typeparam and cascading type param but it's not behaving how I need it to.

Is there some syntax I am missing to get this to work?
I am currently using Code-Behind separation but either examples would be really useful.

For extra context the current component is navigated to directly.

```
[Inject]
private IService<TUser> _service { get; set; }
```

If I try to add the type to the class declaration the .razor page loses all of the properties and fails to build.

```
public partial class Login<TUser> : ComponentBase where TUser : AuthUser, new()
```

Additionally if I remove ComponentBase from the class declaration I can build and run it, however I get the following runtime error when navigating to the page:

```
 Cannot create an instance of Pages.Account.Login`1[TUser] because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

Comment: You can use `services.AddTransient<IService<>, Service<>>();` to register a generic service. That's how `ILogger<T>` is registered. To *inject* such a service though, you need to specify the actual type. `private IService<TUser> _service` can be matched by *any* type that satisfies the constraints of `IService<>`. If you have a generic component you can use that component's type parameter in the service declaration. When you use that generic component you'll specify the concrete type, so the DI middleware will know what type to create

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is that possible? I thought the syntax was: `services.AddTransient(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));`?

Comment: You're right. The point is that you can register generic services by omitting the type parameter

Comment: In your component Razor file you should be able to declare you generic like this:  `@typeparam TUser where TUser : AuthUser, new()` and use the standard syntax in any code behind file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with WASM:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IApiBroker<>), typeof(ApiBroker<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IEntityService<>), typeof(EntityService<>));
```

```cs
public class EntityService<TItem> : IEntityService<TItem>
{
    private readonly IApiBroker<TItem> apiBroker;

    public EntityService(IApiBroker<TItem> apiBroker)
    {
        this.apiBroker = apiBroker;
    }    
    ...
}
```

In a component:

```cs
@code {
    private QuickGrid<Message> grid;

    [Inject]
    private IEntityService<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    private async ValueTask<GridItemsProviderResult<Message>> GridItemsProviderAsync(GridItemsProviderRequest<Message> request)
    {
        return await this.Messages.GridItemsProviderAsync(request, "$orderby=ServerStamp desc");
    }
}
```

### In a Generic Component:

```
@using DbChat.Client.Services.Foundations.Entities;
@typeparam TEntity

<h3>SomeGenericComponent</h3>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private IEntityService<TEntity> service { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public TEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

### Usage

```
<SomeGenericComponent SomeEntity="message" />

@code {
    Message message = new Message();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way that in the component I can still use the generic type and have a single place in the application that defines what TUser is? My intention is for these pages to be extended and different TUsers in different projects. 

I have found a workaround by creating a component that inherits my generic component and supplying the type parameter there successfully, but want to see if theres a way to avoid doing this for every page.

Comment: You could maybe use the [CascadingTypeParameter(...)] feature, which was added in .NET 6. It sets all @typeparam in all subjacent components that have a matching name ("string"). So you'd start in App.razor, create a templated component surrounding your Router tag and cascade it accordingly. Then you'd be able to control the TUser from there for your entire application. I guess. I didn't Try. Otherwise use some kinda generic Transfer Service (https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-wasm/dotnet7/transfer-service-243066).

Comment: @JAL I added a contrived generic component for you.

Comment: @user21986447 I added a contrived generic component for you.

Comment: @Brian Parker Sorry, my bad. I already figured out what the issue was... Let's not talk about it 